# Pivot with Pandas Python to get booleans

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, pivot

I have the following csv: https://github.com/antonio1695/Python/blob/master/nearBPO/facturas.csv

From which I created a dataframe with the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/Antonio/Desktop/nearBPO/facturas.csv", encoding = "ISO-8859-1")
df_du = df.iloc[:,[0,5]]
dfv = df_du.groupby('UUID')['Desc'].apply(list)
df2 = dfv.reset_index()
```

*Note: I'm taking the csv locally.

Which after the code looks like this:

```
    UUID                                       Desc
0   0019A60D-78F8-E341-8D3E-9786201FE017    [TRANSPORTACION DE PASAJEROS]
1   003B8B8F-7017-E441-8C84-8C0EA577E29D    [SERVICIO POR HORA]
2   00536BC1-1B10-4146-A59B-36613090EF10    [CONSUMO Y RENTA DE SALA DE JUNTAS]
3   005BBAEE-ABEC-E341-8CED-15DA22D11F65    [VERIFICACION HOLOGRAMA DOBLE CERO]
4   006C5F2E-CAE0-4498-9288-0241C1949D8A    [C Meg XT Clas CH, Com Whop Q CH, C Meg XT Cla...
5   0075D1FC-996D-4784-9755-2F4598D16163    [Consumo]
```

I would like to make a dataframe which had each element of the 'Desc' column as a column and each UUID as a row where i would have a 1 (or True) if the UUID had the corresponding 'Desc' in it.

Example of what I want:

```
UUID                                     Transportacion de pasajeros    Servicio por hora
0019A60D-78F8-E341-8D3E-9786201FE017     1                              0
003B8B8F-7017-E441-8C84-8C0EA577E29D     0                              1
```

What I was trying was to make was a matrix of 0 with an if to make the 1's. Afterwards I would merge it and pivot it.  However, since the some 'Desc' are the same, I didn't know how big I should do it. And it seems to come along with many other flaws in the merge part.

Comment: Can you try this `df2['Desc'].str.join('___').str.get_dummies('___')`

Comment: I do get the columns, but I don't have the UUID as a reference. Also, I didn't see any 1. It might be just because I didn't saw the whole base, i'll export it to search for 1's. @ayhan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
pd.concat([df2['UUID'], df2['Desc'].str.join('___').str.get_dummies('___')], axis=1)
```

It returns something like this:

```
Out: 
                                   UUID  SERVICIO POR HORA  \
0  0019A60D-78F8-E341-8D3E-9786201FE017                  0   
1  003B8B8F-7017-E441-8C84-8C0EA577E29D                  1   

   TRANSPORTACION DE PASAJEROS  
0                            1  
1                            0
```

Comment: It worked, thanks! It takes a while to run though. Is it normal? Or there is a quicker way? Cause afterwards i'm doing it with something like 1000 times bigger lol.

Comment: @AntonioLópezRuiz At the groupby stage you can use `df_du.groupby('UUID')['Desc'].apply('___'.join)` and at the end you can use `pd.concat([df2['UUID'], df2['Desc'].str.get_dummies('___')], axis=1)`. Not sure if it would dramatically reduce the time though.